# Como evitar la sucesiva ejecucion del boton submit

Tags: php, html, mysql

Los molesto porque no encuentro una funcion que me permita bloquearle al usuario que si apreto el boton Registrar, tenga la posibilidad de volver a hacerlo varias veces. Si ya grabo en la BD el ticket, que el boton quede bloqueado.

```html
                <h3 class="card-title">Datos</h3>
              </div>
              <!-- /.card-header -->
              <!-- form start -->
              <form action="<?= base_url(); ?>usuario/ticket/store" method="POST" role="form" id="form-ticket" enctype="multipart/form-data">

                <div class="card-body">
                  <?php if (!empty(validation_errors())): ?>
                    <div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible">
                      <h5><i class="icon fas fa-ban"></i> Error!</h5>
                      <?php echo validation_errors(); ?>
                    </div>
                  <?php endif ?>

                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Categorías <span style="color:red !important;">*</span></label>
                    <select name="fk_categoria" id="fk_categoria" class="form-control">
                      <option value="">Seleccione una opción</option>
                      <?php foreach ($categorias as $cat) { ?>
                      <option value="<?php echo $cat['id']; ?>"><?php echo $cat['nombre']; ?></option>
                      <?php } ?>
                    </select>
                  </div>

                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Asunto <span style="color:red !important;">*</span></label>
                    <input type="text" name="asunto" value="<?php echo set_value('asunto'); ?>" class="form-control" placeholder="Asunto" autocomplete="off">
                  </div>

                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Imagen</label>
                    <input type="file" name="imagen" class="form-control" placeholder="Imagen" autocomplete="off">
                  </div>

                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Descripción</label>
                    <textarea name="descripcion" id="descripcion" class="form-control" cols="30" rows="10" placeholder="Descripción"></textarea>
                  </div>
                                    
                </div>
                <!-- /.card-body -->
                <div class="card-footer">
                  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success"><i class="fa fa-plus fa fa-white"> </i> Registrar</button>
                </div>
              </form>
```

Muchisimas gracias por todo y espero que se haya entendido.

Comment: No entiendo, cuando se presiona el botón  la página debería refrescar...o estas usando ajax?

Comment: Cuando presiona el boton, si los datos se enviaron a la base de datos y el ticket se cargo, que no pueda volver a presionarlo si la pagina esta cargando o no refresco.

Comment: Reformulo mi pregunta. Entre que el usuario presiona el botón y la pagina realiza el submit, existe un tiempo que permite  a un usuario nervioso realizar muchos clicks a lo loco (antes del submit), provocando llamadas indeseadas al servidor.....es eso??

Comment: Si, una vez que cmpleta los datos puede apretar varias veces el submit hasta que la pagina hace el envio refresca y vuelve al index.

Comment: Puede desactivar el botón utilizando javascript  , aqui tiene una ejemplo de su mismo problema: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3366828/how-to-disable-submit-button-once-it-has-been-clicked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para evitar que se vuelva a pulsar el botón  deshabilitalo:

```
              <button type="submit" onClick="this.form.submit(); this.disabled=true;" class="btn btn-success"><i class="fa fa-plus fa fa-white"> </i> Registrar</button>
```